# How do I set my printer up or check the printers status under the Unity interface

Tags: unity, printing

Unity has me very confused. My printer had a jam but there wasn't any status letting me know under Unity. When I sent a job to the printer the print job icon display and just showed waiting. Pointed firefox at the printer it showed a jam. I tried to dig deeper in Unitys interface but did not find anything referring to printer or any system settings. How do I get to the settings, especially the printer?

The printer is a HP C4750 connected through WIFI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Alt+F2

```
system-config-printer
```

Comment: Is there a settings area from the desktop. If I have to use Alt+F2 and type a command that I may not be familiar with seems very inconvenient. A person could spend a lot of time trying to figure out how set something. Does Unity have any central settings area for peripherals, etc.?

Comment: The system settings (gnome-control-center) can be found as the last item of the log out / shutdown button on the right side of the panel. There you can search for "printer".

Comment: Once you open it you can pin it to the dock. Same with elmicha's comment. Pin the control center to the dock.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I found the system settings under the logout button.